# Как поменять два div местами

Tags: html, css

[image: f]

На скрине. Поменять нужно местами "Уроки" и "Главная". Прикол в том, что у "Уроков" drop меню и если я меняю чисто id и div'ы в html, то drop не работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ответ вам тоже скринами дать ?

Comment: используйте флексбокс - order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
  // Target (this) element is the source node.
  dragSrcEl = this;

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.outerHTML);

  this.classList.add('dragElem');
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  this.classList.add('over');

  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  // this / e.target is previous target element.
  this.classList.remove('over');
}

function handleDrop(e) {

  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(dragSrcEl);
    var dropHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', dropHTML);
    var dropElem = this.previousSibling;
    addDnDHandlers(dropElem);

  }
  this.classList.remove('over');
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  this.classList.remove('over');
}

function addDnDHandlers(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
  elem.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  elem.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);

}

var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
[].forEach.call(cols, addDnDHandlers);
```

```css
[draggable] {
  user-select: none;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}


/* clearfix */

.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.group:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* clearfix-end ========================*/

.wrapper group {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar li a:hover,
.navbar .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background: mediumseagreen;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .dropbtn {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
  }
  .navbar li {
    float: left;
  }
  .content {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar li,
  .content {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="columns" class="navbar">
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown column" draggable="true">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn"> Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: для чего этот js весь ?

Comment: Если Вы видите какое-то другое альтернативное решение, то напишите)

Comment: я не об альтернативе - что он делает ?

Comment: Для элементов меню были описаны события, что анализирует был ли взят какой-то определенный элемент и куда был перемещен, в нашем случае li класса column, в зависимости от этого происходит удаление предыдущей позиции элемента и добавление этого элемента на позицию выбранного, остальные элементы смещаются в зависимости от того, куда был передвинут(перемещен) текущий элемент.

Comment: при попытке drag and drop происходит переадресация